# PHP How right replace element in page?

Tags: php

Good day.

We have **test.php** with next code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST1; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST2; ?>" />
<div class="container">
<p class="test">{Text}</p>
</div>
<!-- STYLE_TEST1 and STYLE_TEST2 - set in define as "/css/styletest1.css" and "/css/styletest2.css" -->
```

and **index.php** with code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("test.php");
$content = ereg_replace("{Text}", 'hello', $content);
echo $content;
```

in **result** we get code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST1; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST2; ?>" />
<div class="container">
<p class="test">{Text}</p>
</div>
```

we have problem with styles, becose `echo $content;` print `<?php echo STYLE_TEST1; ?>` and `<?php echo STYLE_TEST2; ?>` and not replace on values which set in define for this elements(not change on "/css/styletest1.css" and "/css/styletest2.css").

*Tell me please how right make replace?*

P.S.: we need that styles was include in file `test.php`, ie file **test.php** should have lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST1; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST2; ?>" />
```

Comment: you are basically echoing php script... you can't do that... that's like this `echo '<?php echo 'hi';?>';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP file\_get\_contents with php intact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061032/php-file-get-contents-with-php-intact)

Comment: @Anonymous tell mep please how replace my code if use `ob` ?

Comment: You take the returned value and replace the values that you desire.

Comment: @Anonymous i right understand - http://pastebin.com/ihT6bGpZ ?

Comment: Yes, you can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Thanks all for help!

*This is the best decision for me on my question*

```
function getTemplate($file) {

    ob_start(); // start output buffer

    include $file;
    $template = ob_get_contents(); // get contents of buffer
    ob_end_clean();
    return $template;

}

$content = getTemplate("test.php");
$content = ereg_replace("{Text}", 'hello', $content);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix this is to make it a variable....

just make sure you have

```
define("STYLE_TEST1", "/css/styletest1.css");
define("STYLE_TEST2", "/css/styletest2.css");
```

**test.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST1; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo STYLE_TEST2; ?>" />
<div class="container">
<p class="test">{<?=$variable?>}</p>
</div>
<!-- STYLE_TEST1 and STYLE_TEST2 - set in define as "/css/styletest1.css" and "/css/styletest2.css" -->
```

**index.php**

```
$variable = 'hello';

include 'test.php';
```

**The result will be:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styletest1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styletest2.css" />
<div class="container">
<p class="test">{hello}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: see p.s. in question please

Comment: the styles are included in test.php... can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @learner I changed it a bit... it should still work if you defined the variables correctly...

Comment: nice, why <?= (what it is)?

Comment: @learner it's called a [short open tag](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) and it basically replaces `<?php echo $this; ?>` to `<?=$this?>`